# "No record found for traveler" error when I try to look up my US travel history - is there a way to get this corrected?

Tags: usa, i-94

The [official CBP website](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search) provides a handy way of searching for one's travel history. Up until a few weeks ago it worked flawlessly and I could easily track my travels. However now I'm seeing a strange error when I type in my details:

[image: Enter Your Traveler Info. No record found for traveler]

What is the reason behind this and can I somehow get this corrected? Do note that I can successfully retrieve my I-94 (so my passport details are correct) and friends are reporting that travel history lookup is still working correctly on their end.

Update from 2021: still seeing the same error, not sure what would be required to get it corrected.

Comment: I get the same message, even with different variations of my name.  (My first name is merely W and people often refuse to believe that.). Also tried putting the name in all caps.

Comment: @WGroleau aren't you a US citizen? The I-94 website does not record data for US citizens.

Comment: Jonathan Reez: my wife began seeing this message a couple of years ago.  We noticed this after she was stamped into the US in her expired passport, though I do not know whether that is relevant, and I do not know whether the change occurred immediately after that happened, or perhaps even before.

Comment: I'm actually seeing almost the opposite - My 'most recent I-94" shows my last entry as Dec 20, 2019, but my travel history shows four more entries into the US since that date

Comment: I have the same problem when trying to check my online I-94. Didn't have any trouble visiting on my last trip in Feb. It seems to not be that uncommon.

Comment: @phoog—yeah; I misinterpreted the blurb on the bottom.  I've sent FOIA requests more than once to the office that is supposed to provide such records to citizens, with no response.

Comment: As another datapoint, I checked and am able to access mine, and it is up to date with all entries/exits that would be recorded.

Comment: My travel history shows record not found. It was working earlier. Anyone knows how to retreive the data?

Answer (score 2):

Tried this with 2 relatives who visited us who are not US citizens.

All had same result when using CURRENT passport number on which they last entered US.

However, using PRIOR passport number on which they first entered US, am able to see Travel History without problem. Of note, last I-94, unfortunately, gives last I-94 under OLD passport.