# "The data from the server was incorrect" error when looking up one's I-94

Tags: usa, i-94

When looking up my I-94 on the [official CBP website](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/recent-search) I see the following error:

> The data from the server was incorrect.

I'm seeing the same error while looking it up for another fellow traveler. Is the CBP website broken?

Comment: [Related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158506/no-record-found-for-traveler-error-when-i-try-to-lookup-my-us-travel-history). They seem to be having a lot of issues in the past year...

Comment: I don't think this needs a downvote. I hit the same issue, googling brought me to this page and the solution below actually worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me, I was trying to access the website on my company laptop, opening on my personal laptop on Chrome solved the issue.

Comment: Does that mean Google is now collaborating with NSA instead of competing with them?

Comment: This answer worked for me. Disconnecting my VPN and retrying; helped me get past the error.